# Creating a Label in each of my custom cell in cellForRowIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I am trying to create a label in each of my customCells. In cellForRowIndexPath, I have:

EDIT:

```
static NSString *checkInTableIdendifier = @"ChatCell";

cell = (ChatTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:checkInTableIdendifier];

if (cell == nil){
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ChatTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

NSAttributedString *title;
title = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[self.savedMsgs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Noteworthy-Bold" size:12], NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @1 , NSStrokeColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor]}]; //1
UILabel *label;
label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( (self.view.bounds.size.width - title.size.width) / 2.0f, 40.0f, title.size.width, title.size.height)]; //2
label.attributedText = title; //3
[cell addSubview:label]; //4
```

The label will all end up in the same point overlapping each other because of line 2. How can I represent the origin of the label generated according to each respective cell?

Comment: Could you post the entire contents of this method? I'm guessing this is a cell reuse issue so if you could post the rest of the code I could let you know how to fix it.

Comment: @Acey added the rest of my code in cellForRowIndexPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are using to generate cells, 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier' can return a cell that has already been used before. When you add your labels etc after getting the cell, you are adding labels on top of labels that are already there.

The easiest way to handle cell reuse is to create a UITableViewCell subclass and an associated xib. After this ViewController is created and the tableView is accessible (viewDidLoad, usually) register the nib for the cell to the tableView. Then when you dequeue the cell, you need only to set the text values on the labels that are already there.

An aside, UITableView had a newer better method for dequeuing cells that takes an index path and always returns a cell so you don't need to nil check it. I would switch to that if you don't need to support iOS 6.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the cell's bounds, not self.view's to position the label. Be careful as the frame might change after the cell has been created, so it's recommended to use auto layout to ensure the label is always positioned when you want it to be in respect to the cell.

Also, remember that the cell get reused in which case you might end up adding the label multiple times.

To mitigate both issues, subclass the cell and design it in the accompanying xib.